For a Guidewire Project, The event is not triggering the Rules in a Clustered Environment
We have added a newEvent from the PCF(UI)for Guidewire Claim Center . Once the user updates ant fields we have written the code to create a newEvent , which in turn will trigger the Event Fired Rule and the Payload generation.
When we check this functionality in a non clustered env we are fine no issues here . But when we test the functionality in a clustered environment (Separate UI and batch servers) the functionality is not triggering on the UI server . Its a Load balancer URL so the user will always be logged in the UI server and not the batch server. Can someone help with this.
The config.xml is accurately setup . This issue is happening only for one single integration all the others work fine.
The config.xml is accurately setup . This issue is happening only for one single integration all the others work fine.

As per my understanding, the message gets created on any one of the servers having the "messaging" role, irrespective of how and where the rule got fired. How did you conclude that the event didn't fire? The control never goes to the message transport plugin if the destination is suspended. Do you have at least one server with the "messaging" role? Some additional context around your rule and debugging details would be required to help you further.

This is slightly incorrect I believe. I think the message gets created by the node that triggers the event (and thus triggers the event fired rules). The processing of the message in the queue is handled only by nodes with the messaging role. One way to determine if the message is being created is to suspend the messaging destination, then trigger the event to ensure a message is placed into the queue. Then you can resume the queue to see if the node with the messaging role processes the message. Also a little more details like ClaimCenter version or a screenshot of the cluster UI might help.

Message gets created from the node where the operation(Event trigger) is performed, and the processing(Transport)  takes place which is the messaging server role node. All these depends on how the code is being written.

Is that another way of saying, "We still don't have enough information about your Guidewire rules even to speculate why events might not be getting triggered."?
